# Sum of a Finite Sequence of Terms:$18, 25, 32, 39, ... ,67$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Ok I know this question maybe too easy.

What is the sum of a finite sequence of terms? $$18, 25, 32, 39, ... ,67$$

The answer is $340$.

I use the formula:

$${ S = \frac{n}{2} \times (a_1 + a_n) }$$

$${ n = \frac{a_n-a_1}{7} }$$ whrere $7$ is the difference between every iteration

I get $297.5$

Am I missing something or is the problem set wrong? Any Hint?

Comment: You're forgetting to count the first element when you calculate n. So it's actually $1+\dfrac{a_n-a_1}{a_2 - a_1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is rather
$$
a_n=a_1+(n-1)\times 7
$$ giving
$$
n \color{red}{-1}= \frac{a_n-a_1}{7}
$$ thus here 
$$n=\frac{67-18}{7}+\color{red}{1}=\color{blue}{8}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

There are 8 terms. So n = 8. That will give you the right answer